# How to configure php-fpm in magento2.4.4 on CentOS server

Tags: ssh, command, magento2.4.5, version-upgrade

after upgrading magento version , commands not working.

https://prnt.sc/OOxHHF7WVLyR

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue when you upgrade to magento 2.4.4. It's not ssh, php-fpm issue.

Solution 1: Update the composer.json file specifically the require-dev section with what is written here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/composer.json

Solution2: Do the following steps:

1. STAY IN PHP 7.4
2. composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
3. composer update
4. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update
6. composer update
7. CHANGE TO PHP 8.1
8. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35306